# Convert existing TCP socket into TLS using OpenSSL

Tags: c++, ssl, tcp, openssl

I need some information about OpenSSL, TLS socket. First of i want to made a connection with server through TLS over TCP.
Generally first create a TCP socket, then connect to server using the TCP socket, after that convert(before send or receive any data through TCP socket) the TCP socket into TLS.

My question is is it possible according to following way?

1. Create TCP socket.
2. Connect with server using TCP socket.
3. Send and receive some data through TCP socket.
4. Then convert the TCP socket into TLS.

   Note: I am using OpenSSL.

Answer (score 2):

It seems possible in the given way provided that the server must support it. See SMTP. It works in this way for SMTP server where first few conversation is in plain TCP then over SSL/TLS. You can bind an existing socket to a BIO using BIO_new_socket and then set this socket to SSL * structure using SSL_set_bio.

You can find many examples of SSL client.

Comment: I am using OpenSSl API to the above conversion pSslSocket = new SslSocket;
 pSslSocket->connect(iTcpSocket);
 pSslSocket->finishNegotiation(10 * 1000);

Comment: OpenSSL is C-based library. It does not look like OpenSSL code. Is SslSocket a wrapper over OpenSSL?

Comment: Yes SslSocket is a wrapper class over OpenSSL.

Comment: In connect method i am doing this  BIO* sbio = BIO_new_socket(...)
  SSL_set_bio(...)
  SSL_set_connect_state(..);

  SSL_connect(..)

Comment: It seems fine to me. Did you face any issue on it?

Comment: One confusion to me if i convert a TCP socket into TLS in the middle then how server will know about it? Is there any application level notification needed?

Comment: Yes, you might want to do something like issuing a STARTTLS notification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS